# DynamoDB FilterExpression with multiple condition javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table with partition key and sort key also 2 other columns. I am unable to get items using **FilterExpression** for multiple conditions with **AND** in DynamoDB using javaScript AWS SDK. Can anyone provide correct code to retrieve data with multiple conditions in FilterExpression?
My code is as follows:

```
var params = {
    TableName: 'Department',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#company = :companyId'
    , ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#company': 'CompanyID',
        '#dType': 'DepartmentType',
        '#cTime': 'CreatedTime'
    }
    , ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':companyId': 'Test',
        ':deptType': dType,
        ':daysPrior': 1250456879634
    },FilterExpression: '#dType = :deptType AND #ts > :daysPrior' 
};
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

There is typo error in the format in your query(after `CreatedTime`)
To keep it clean, use either double quotes or single quotes but not both.
I have used double quotes, just the way aws sample codes are there.

```
var params = {
    TableName: "Department",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#company = :companyId", 
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#company": "CompanyID",
        "#dType": "DepartmentType",
        "#cTime": "CreatedTime" //here
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":companyId": "Test",
        ":deptType": dType,
        ":daysPrior": 1250456879634
    },
    FilterExpression: "#dType = :deptType AND #cTime > :daysPrior" 
};
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you need a bit more complex filter expressions to scan or query your DynamoDB table, you could use brackets, for example:

```
var params = {
    TableName: "Department",
    ...
    FilterExpression: "(not (#type <> :type and #company = :company)) or (#timestamp > :timestamp)",
    ...
};
```

Note: this example filter expression does not have a particular meaning.